# How to create a sequence that increases its step in R

Tags: r, sequence

I'm trying to create a sequence that increases its step by one at each interval, but can't manage to do that.

I would like my result to look like this:

```
vec <- c(1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55)
```

So basically, starting from 1, each index is equal to the precedent plus a number that is increasing by 1 step by step, something like

```
[i]=[i-1]+seq(from=i, to=10, by=1)
```

but of course this is not the correct notation.

How would you set this up in order to get something like shown in `vec`? I imagine some loop is necessary in order to have an indices in a vector exponentially increasing.

Comment: `trying to creating a sequence` what tools do you intend to use? (The notation you show at the bottom isn't that far from some out there.) Can you ask something more specific than `Any help?`?

Comment: Is this R? Please read [ask].

Comment: Sorry, first question here! Yes, this is in R, forgot to mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the [Triangular Number Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) and has the form:

`Tn = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + n`

This can be created with the `cumsum` function in R:

```
cumsum(1:10)
# [1]  1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55
```

or something like this if you prefer recursion:

```
tri_num = function(n){
  if(n <= 1){
    return(1)
  }else{
    return(n+tri_num(n-1))
  }
}

sapply(1:10, tri_num)
```

Comment: Or `(1:10)*((1:10)-1)/2` in a closed form. The n'th number is in the sequence is n*(n-1)/2

Comment: @geotheory sure, this works too, but `cumsum` seems to be more efficient